# Sorting orderlines with different criteria in linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I've tried used OrderByDescending and OrderBy however I was not able to get correct result.

Here are sample of data to sort:

```
ol1.SKU = "323";
ol1.SubTotal = 12;

ol2.SKU = "Avante";
ol2.SubTotal = 12;

ol3.SKU = "143";
ol3.SubTotal = 13456;

ol4.SKU = "444";
ol4.SubTotal = 2;

ol5.SKU = "znote";
ol5.SubTotal = 0;
```

The kind of result I wanted after sorting:

```
Output:
ol3
ol2
ol1
ol4
ol5
```

The rules in sorting orderlines:

1. Most expensive (SubTotal) SKU first
2. Any SKU which contains the string AVANTE
3. All other line items
4. Notes(ZNote) are last.

I have tried like this but it is not returning the correct output.

```
private List<OrderLine> SortByOrderlines(List<OrderLine> ol)
{
    return ol.OrderByDescending(x => x.SubTotal).ThenByDescending(x => x.SKU == "AVANTE").OrderBy(x => x.SKU == "ZNOTE").ToList();
}
```

Comment: If you want to search for string that Contain avante you probably need to do that `(x => x.SKU.Contains("AVANTE"))`

Comment: Can you explain. How is the result "not the correct one"?

Comment: In your sample, `ol3` appears twice and `ol4` doesn't appear at all. Is that correct?

Comment: You code has `OrderBy...ThenByDescending...OrderBy`. That will last `OrderBy` will throw away everything done before it. You probably want `OrderBy...ThenByDescending...ThenBy`

Comment: @canton7 I have updated

Answer (score 1):

```
    class OrderLine
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SKU { get; set; }
        public int SubTotal { get; set; } 
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = new OrderLine[] {
                new OrderLine {
                    Id = 1,
                    SKU = "323",
                    SubTotal = 12
                },
                new OrderLine {
                    Id = 2,
                    SKU = "Avante",
                    SubTotal = 12
                },
                new OrderLine {
                    Id = 3,
                    SKU = "143",
                    SubTotal = 13456
                },
                new OrderLine {
                    Id = 4,
                    SKU = "444",
                    SubTotal = 2
                },
                new OrderLine {
                    Id = 5,
                    SKU = "znote",
                    SubTotal = 0
                },
            };

            var sortedData = data
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.SubTotal)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.SKU.ToUpper().Contains("AVANTE"))
                .ThenByDescending(x => !x.SKU.ToUpper().Contains("AVANTE") || x.SKU.ToUpper() != "ZNOTE")
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.SKU.ToUpper() == "ZNOTE");

            System.Console.WriteLine(
                string.Join(", ", sortedData.Select(d => d.Id))
            );

        }
    }
```

I hope this code can help you to better understand what could be problematic with your implementation.

I have to mention that according to your specifications of the rules you have to use the "Contains" method.
Also, I've assumed that you desire Descending ordering for the mentioned rules (including the last one). However, as others mentioned the most crucial problem with your implementation is the use of "OrderBy" rather than "ThenBy" which destroys the previous orderings.
It is also worth mentioning that if you want to precisely implement the rules (specially the third one) you have to add another piece to order the "other things" before the "znote". Finally, if you want to be exact with your comparison of strings with litterals, normalization of them to the same format will be helpful.

Comment: I've used your sample data and it prints 3, 2, 1, 4, 5 which is the same order you've mentioned. Could you give another example in which the order is not what you want?